# Google Contacts API issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, oauth, google-contacts-api

Am trying to use google contacts api, if I use

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full

am getting 25contacts, but if i try to get more contacts in single request, it gives me "Unauthorized" error. below is the request.

Moreover, if I add any quesy string to the above url, i get unauthorized error

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/ful?filterby=emails&max_results=1000&oauth_token=1%2FtKP60-hjdz5II2rimvgKtIHHzEiiPlA95fS2hl1eBr4&oauth_consumer_key=www.mydomain.com&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1306390988&oauth_nonce=1278946&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=mhCioGAKdAwBCMxdzJtfBU6rE%2FQ%3D

Please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I guess it it max-results=1000 (not max_results). You may give it a try. In SocialAuth.NET component max-results is used it returns all contacts automatically by just calling GetContacts()... It hides all confusions of signatures, URLs, tokens bla bla.
http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/